# Sencha Touch 2 App with Cordova 3.1 run slowly iOS 7

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ios7, sencha-touch-2

I have build an application with Sencha Touch 2. 
I compiled it with xCode 5, using Cordova 3.1. It run well in my iPad with iOS 6.0, but when I actualized to iOS 7.0 the App doesn't work well, it runs very very slowly. How can I resolved this problem?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Please run the system log to see errors if there are.

Command to see the logs

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

run this command from terminal and let me know the errors